# Can we add something about how to properly ask and answer a question to the FAQ

Tags: discussion, proposed-faq, standards

We are getting more new users here and the quality of the questions and answers is taking a hit.  I think a short blurb in the FAQ on how to ask a good question and the requirements for a good answer would help in this area a lot.  If nothing else it will give us a place to point
new users for help. It may also help alievate the frustration that new users can feel when their first attempts to ask or answer a question fail to meet the standards that have been set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For about a month, we've been experimenting with sharing a new article:

- [Welcome to New Users](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users).

A reference is commonly (not universally) included to it in comments on newbie's first questions and answers. Feel free to mention it (nicely!) in your own comments.

It includes references to two meta-questions:

- [FAQ: What are the attributes of a good question?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/882/faq-what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question)
- [FAQ: What makes an answer good on Skeptics.SE?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/faq-what-makes-an-answer-good-on-skeptics-se)

I thought it had been working reasonably well. (Certainly, there hasn't been any backlash against it, which has been an improvement on previous attempts!)

So, in a way, I am answering your question by saying "we already do that". However, I don't think I am really answering your question: if you think it is still a problem, maybe these aren't working well enough. I certainly welcome suggestions on how to improve the wording of what we have or what new techniques we should try.

Comment: This works just fine.  I had not seen it since generally when I see you have addressed the issue I ignored the post.  I think adding that link to the FAQ would still be a great benefit.

Comment: @Chad, when you say "adding that link to the FAQ", you are stepping into a minefield! Which FAQ do you mean? There are so many, there is [actually a FAQ about all the different FAQs](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/981/all-the-different-faqs). If you mean the one linked at the top of the page, it isn't something that the Stack Exchange software permits us (i.e. the skeptics) to edit.

Comment: OK I Assumed with the link to the meta about notable claims we could do some customization.